# Unable to access internet when connected to cisco anyconnect vpn client

Tags: cisco-anyconnect

Users were able to connect to the internet before while they are connected to cisco anyconnect vpn client but now a days they are unable to browse internet without any changes from the firewall side. Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: The “firewall side” being where, between the VPN server and the internet? Are you using split tunneling?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielB, from my firewall side the VPN cisco anyconnect configured in Cisco Firewall, Yes I am using split tunneling. Then the cisco anyconnect vpn software is installed on user's laptop. They used to connect via cisco anyconnect vpn while they are working from home. Before, when they are connected to cisco anyconnect vpn, they can still browse on the internet but now a days they cannot browse on internet. we have one user, she can able to browse if she is using mobile data as personal hotspot but when she connected to their home wifi she cannot again browse on internet